# How to break a Value inside URL

Tags: android, retrofit2

i am trying to inflate the spinner from the URL
having Data as

[{"DATABASE_NAME":"Comp0049:Company One "}

i have inflated it successfully into my spinner. my problem is i don't want the Comp0049: in my spinner but the company name. is there any way to break the values inside the URL.

Comment: just split the string with ":" and then you will have both things in an array then you will get data in index 1

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham Answered:

```
String s = "Comp0049:Company One"

String cName = s.contains(":")? s.split(":")[1]: s;
```

Where if will first check if the String contains `:` if yes, will split and take the second element in the array else use the original string.

Comment: i am having number of companies. should i run this in loop?

Comment: yes, if you have an array of strings then use a for loop, if you have a cursor, there can be better ways as cursor has its own iterators.